# Sensible Mac OS X Anti-malware Precautions

Tags: macos, mac, security, malware

Given that complacency probably isn't the best idea what do people believe the right approach to staying safe when using Mac OS X is.

Not doing dumb stuff and staying patched are pretty obvious but are there other things which Mac OS X users should be doing?

Comment: Please search for other similar questions, such as this: http://superuser.com/questions/6778/free-mac-os-x-anti-virus-software

Comment: Anti-malware precautions doesn't just = anti-virus.  Firewalls, sensible behaviour, anti-spyware, browser choice, patching...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any real reason why you should not be making precautions that PC/Windows users have been doing for ages now? I don't see why you should be expected to do something above and beyond the same common sense practices that have been proven tried and true by PC users for years.

- Don't open and download attachments from email you don't trust
- Have good anti-virus and anti-malware software running
- Have a decent firewall set up to prevent intrusions
- If you think a site is shady, don't go to it and don't download crap from it.
- And if you still aren't sure, ask a PC user who already knows.

Comment: But the Apple commercial told me that only PCs get viruses!!!

Comment: And Steve Ballmer told me Vista "good" and "worked".  They all lie...